# Helper column to get away from array formula

Tags: excel

I have an array formula to pick out distinct values in a list. However, with the list sometimes being over 15,000 lines, the array formula is very slow. Is there a way that I can add a helper column to speed things up? (I can't use a Pivot Table for this)

So I have a list starting in B2 that has values such as 01.01, 01.02, 02.04, 04.08 etc. (my list is sorted from smallest to biggest in this column). Each of these values can occur over 500 times. The name of my list is TaskCode. I was using the array formula `{=INDEX(TaskCode,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$1:C1,TaskCode),0))}` and also found a regular formula `=INDEX(TaskCode,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,TaskCode),0,0),0))`. Both of these are pretty slow, especially when you start getting to 20 and 30 thousand lines. I also considered using an occurrence column `=COUNTIF($C$1:C1,C1)` (dragged down) and then pick out the 1's. However, I don't know the best way to pick out the 1's quickly.

Anyway, any help on speeding this process up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does it do? can you provide a small sample table with input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a helper "ID" column, with the formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH($B2,$B$1:$B1,0)), MAX($C$1:$C1)+1,"")
```

This should be quicker as each cell is only looking at the range of cells above, rather than the entire "TaskCode" column.

You can then use a static ID, along with `INDEX`/`MATCH` to get a distinct list of TaskCodes:

[image]

**EVEN BETTER**

If you can be sure that your TaskCodes are ALWAYS sorted smallest to largest, you will only ever have to check the cell immediately above:

```
=IF($B2=$B1,"", MAX($C$1:$C1)+1)
```

[image]